# How to group database tables using Group By

Tags: php, mysql, database, group-by

I am developing a simple php shopping cart site which connected to a databse named products and has tables Orders,user,products. The orders table has the following fields :
OrderId , product_id , user_id , quantity ... When the user orders for example 3 products . The data is inserted from `SESSION['cart']`  Below is the query

```
$query = "insert into orders (product_id,user_id,Quantity) values ('$key','$id','$value')"; 
                mysql_query($query);
```

Now the problem is if user orders more than one product, three orderID's are generated, because he ordered 3 products and each orderId refers to that product. When i use the select statement it shows all the orders of the users but i want to group them, So that if person ordered more than 1 products at a time, the list would show me single orderID but all the products with the user who ordered it. Below is the image of database table record from orders table and the select query i am using ..

```
OrderId  product_id  user_id  Quantity
```

---

```
  1           4        1           1
  3          21        1           3
  4          19        1           1
  5          21        1           3
  6          19        1           2

$sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders,USER WHERE user.`user_id`=orders.`user_id`"); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
    {
        $sReturn .='
                <tr>
                <td>' . $row['user_id'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['OrderId'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['product_id'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $row['Quantity'] . '</td>
                </tr>';
    }
```

What select query can be used someone told me groupby with sum ..

Comment: Can you show a sample output of what you would like it to look like?

Comment: you should not use order id as auto increment....

Comment: I want to show a table where i can view list of users along with the order_id... i have come up with a query below which gives me user_id and NumberofOrders of the user, i also want quantity summed up  .. SELECT user.`user_id`,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN USER
ON Orders.user_id=user.`user_id`
GROUP BY username;

Comment: @BabarAli you cant retrieve order id with this structure.

Comment: Wheels need reinventing, but why this one?

Answer (score 1):

this will get u the sum of products by each user according to product_id

**Updated**

```
 SELECT SUM( orders.Quantity ) , COUNT( orders.order_id ) , orders.user_id
    FROM  orders join user on (user.`user_id`=orders.`user_id`) 
    GROUP BY orders.user_id
```

Comment: it generates error,. something is wrong with the query

Comment: Nope tried small, capital .. still getting error    Error Code: 1052
Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: yes i have changed my query, you can check now. actually there is a feild user_id in users table also thats why it is showing  "Error Code: 1052 Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous "

Comment: Thankyou Habib your query works fine now but its still not what i wanted.. it shows user_id three times so ,, i will use it in the details of the user orders page .. when the admin clicks on the user order history your query would work ... i have figured out the query ..replying to answer the question

Comment: @BabarAli you confused me a lot, what you post as an answer is not what your question tells us?? I have changed my answer and now finally I guess It is what you want..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a table called something like OrderItem or OrderRow where you put the product information for each order. Fields could be OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, ItemPrice.

It's a good idea to store the price you told the customer at the time of ordering, otherwise you will get a lot of problems when changing prices in the future.

Comment: first i was thinking to create a bridge table which stores user_id order_id , i have a table named orders which have the following fields (orderID,product_id,user_id,quantity) .. How will it be managed if i add price column to this table ... as the price is mentioned in products table.

Comment: When customers are in the store show prices from products. After they made a purchase you probably have a page for their order(s). There you use the price from their order.

Comment: Got it .,.. Thanks idstam :) .. ill add price product field ..and at the orders page ill select price from the orders table

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your `order_id` - it cant be autoincrement.  Then this is what I think you are asking.

```
select order_id, sum(quantity)
from orders
group by order_id
```

I have left the where clause out as I dont know what filter you will want on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id =
(SELECT user_id FROM order_table WHERE order_id = n limit 1);
```

But much better if you will create separate table for order which containing order info and table for linking an order and a products (id, order_id, product_id, quantity).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the query .. below is the query for getting number of orders + Quantity or Number OF Products + user_id ...

```
    SELECT user.`user_id`,SUM(quantity) AS Number_Of_Products,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN USER
ON Orders.user_id=user.`user_id`
GROUP BY username;
```

below is the output

```
user_id  Number_Of_Products  NumberOfOrders
```

---

```
  1                  10                 5
```